# parser with structure (php)

Tags: php, parsing, command, structure

I have a command parser that each command has similar structure(parse, validate, execute, confirmation/error), but they all do something different(open, close, addnote, changestatus).

I was asked to change the error message and had to do the same change to all the commands separately, as they all have different parameters and pull from different tables in the database. But they are all mostly the same. Is there an easier way to do this? (rather than a switch-case and hardcode all the commands)

I know that there are more changes to come and I'd rather not copy/paste, change 2 words to each command every time, especially since I know they want to double the number of commands...

```
validate($commands){
 foreach($commands as $command){
  switch($command['name']){
    case 'close':
      validateClose($command);
      break;
    case 'addnote:
      validateAddnote($command);
      break;
  ...
   }
  }
 }

execute($commands){
 foreach($commands as $command){
  switch($command['name']){
    case 'close':
      executeClose($command);
      break;
    case 'addnote:
      executeAddnote($command);
      break;
  ...
   }
  }
 }

validateClose($command){
  // parse here for parameters, 3
  // validate parameters
  $command['valid'] = $validated;
  if(!$validated)
     $message = "Invalid because...";
}

validateAddnote($command){
  // parse here for parameters, 1
  // validate parameters
  $command['valid'] = $validated;
  if(!$validated)
     $message = "Invalid because...";
}

...

executeClose($command){
   $db->status('close', params);
   $message = "closed x with {params}";
}

executeAddnote($command){
   $db->add('note', param);
   $message = "Added {param} as note to x";
}

 ...
```

Comment: VERY difficult to help when there are no code examples or demonstration of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to go with abstraction and create a class for the commands with an abstract class and a child class for each command.

I'm throwing out the switch and using variable class names for creating the instances of each command.

These changes really cleaned things up, made it more readable, and made it more flexible and to easily make changes to either a single command, or all commands at once without repetition.